# How to crop an image width svg?

Tags: css, svg

How to crop an image with path in this svg?

```
<svg width="1440" height="568" viewBox="0 0 1440 568" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 0H1440V481.821L720 568L0 481.821V0Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="720" y1="607.026" x2="720" y2="35.2649" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#0997FF" stop-opacity="0.56"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I want to set linearGradient of svg on an image and extra space in bottom of image be as same as background color of body(navy blue):

```
<div class="bg"></div>


.bg {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: url("../assets/images/mySvg.svg"),
     url("../assets/images/myImage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: So what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: you can do it by changing the viewBox and removing the height attribute. Please edit your question and add some more details to your question. For example what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I added more details to the question. @enxaneta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the image into the SVG.

- Combine the image and the gradient into an SVG group (`<g>`)
- Then clip that group with an SVG `<clipPath>` defined using your original path.
- Put the SVG inside the `<div>`

```css
body {
  background-color: linen;
}

.bg {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1440 568">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <path d="M0 0H1440V481.821L720 568L0 481.821V0Z"/>
      </clipPath>

      <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="720" y1="607.026" x2="720" y2="35.2649" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0997FF" stop-opacity="0.56"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
      <image xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/1440/568" width="1440" height="568"/>
      <rect width="1440" height="568" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <p>More content here.</p>
</div>
```